# 2 UITableViewCells side by side without a custom background image?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I'm trying to make something like this in my iPhone app:

[image]

Is there an easy-ish way to do this without making background images and such? I'm following a "Drawing a Grid in a UITableView" guide found here: http://usxue.is-programmer.com/posts/14176.html but so far I can't get the rounded edges with borders like a normal grouped table view has.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

After looking around and running into issues, I think my best bet is just to make two UIButton objects here. A LOT EASIER than what I was trying to do.